# I want to detect similar meaning in sentence "in my final year web based system"

Tags: predictive-modeling

When students submit a topic for his/her final year research, the system should be able to detect that this topic was carried on by some student or already exists.

How can I be able to do it? If its a model, how can embed python in php database?

[image]

Comment: This one of core objectives for my final year project.

Answer (score 1):

The simple option is to implement it as a text search, preferably enriched with [tf-idf weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) and/or ignoring stop words: in theory all the possible topics (documents) are encoded as tf-idf vectors. When a query is provided it's also encoded as a tf-idf vector, then compared against all the documents vectors, typically with [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). The results are then ordered by the similarity score.

In practice various efficiency techniques can be used (the most obvious one is not to represent the vectors as sparse vectors).

There are obviously more advanced techniques, but it can get pretty complex so I would start with this simple option first and then consider improvements later.

Comment: Could you please help me understand how can use tf-idf and consine similarity in this case because I am seeing these algorithms for the firsttime.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials available since this is a very common technique. For instance a quick search with "most similar documents cosine tf idf" gives these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118720/python-tf-idf-cosine-to-find-document-similarity, https://towardsdatascience.com/tf-idf-for-document-ranking-from-scratch-in-python-on-real-world-dataset-796d339a4089. The latter seems to explain the principle quite well, but you might have to adapt some of the technical details to your case (typically the pre-processing steps might differ).